# Debezium Kafka connector mongodb : Error connecting kafka connector to mongodb

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium, mongodb-kafka-connector

Below are my MongoDB config in /etc/kafka/connect-mongodb-source.properties

```
name=mongodb-source-connector 
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector 
mongodb.hosts=/remoteserveraddress:27017 
mongodb.name=mongo_conn 
initial.sync.max.threads=1 
tasks.max=1
```

but getting below error

```
 ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector' was not found. Returning: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader@5a058be5 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:165)
```

Running connector in standalone mode.

I have mongodbconnector class under debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0.Final.jar

also classpath is set as follows

```
#for CLASSPATH
CLASSPATH=/Users/111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/*
export CLASSPATH
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
export PATH
```

Using plugin path I see its able to register and load all required plugins..

```
[2020-01-10 08:14:07,916] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:78)
[2020-01-10 08:14:07,942] INFO Loading plugin from: /Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/mongodb-driver-3.11.1.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:241)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,082] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/mongodb-driver-3.11.1.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:264)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,083] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.AllConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,083] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.PrincipalConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,083] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.NoneConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,085] INFO Loading plugin from: /Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0.Final.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:241)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,120] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0.Final.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:264)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,121] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,121] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,121] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,122] INFO Loading plugin from: /Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/debezium-core-1.0.0.Final.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:241)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,198] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/debezium-core-1.0.0.Final.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:264)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,198] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.converters.ByteBufferConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,199] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,199] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,199] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,199] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,200] INFO Loading plugin from: /Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/mongo-kafka-0.2-all.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:241)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,340] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/mongo-kafka-0.2-all.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:264)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,340] INFO Added plugin 'com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,340] INFO Added plugin 'com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:193)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,341] INFO Loading plugin from: /Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/bson-3.11.1.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:241)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,373] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/bson-3.11.1.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:264)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,373] INFO Loading plugin from: /Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:241)
[2020-01-10 08:14:08,465] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/Users/1111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0/mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:264)
```

but at the end again same issue

```
    [2020-01-10 08:40:43,613] ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector' was not found. Returning: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader@33f2df51 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:165)
[2020-01-10 08:40:43,809] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:121)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: username can not be null
    at com.mongodb.MongoCredential.<init>(MongoCredential.java:350)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCredential.<init>(MongoCredential.java:344)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCredential.createCredential(MongoCredential.java:169)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ConnectionContext.<init>(ConnectionContext.java:69)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector.validate(MongoDbConnector.java:222)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:115)
[2020-01-10 08:40:43,810] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:66)
```

output of >curl localhost:8083/connector-plugins

```
[{"class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"0.2"},{"class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"0.2"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.3.2"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.3.2"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.3.2"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.3.2"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.3.2"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jms.JmsSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.3.2"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.3.2"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.3.2"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.3.2-ce"},{"class":"io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector","type":"source","version":"1.0.0.Final"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStr
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues

1. Debezium connector has hardcoded source='admin'and there is no way to overwrite it and the DB server I was trying to connect didn't had any admin as authentication.
2. Test server that I was using was standalone server and had no replica, so I had to create replica and add this server to it.
   Debezium connector doesnt support standalone servers.

Comment: The first one (configurable auth source) has been fixed for the upcoming Debezium 1.1.0.Alpha1 release.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please check the installation of your plugin using the Kafka Connect REST Interface (see details [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html#get--connector-plugins-)).

Try to install Kafka Connect plugins using the `plugin path` mechanism instead of `CLASSPATH` (more info in the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#installing-plugins)).

Comment: thanks for your answer.I have tried with plugin path too, below is the path in connect-standalone.properties as well as connect-avro-standalone.properties, still same issue, it's not able to load  Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector... though I see its able to register all required loaders in the start of the log from the specified location and added plugins.                                                                
         {plugin.path=/Users/11111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent- 5.3.2/debezium-debezium-connector-mongodb-1.0.0}

Comment: Try `plugin.path=/Users/11111111/workspace/KafkaConnect/confluent-5.3.2`. Your plugins should be inside `plugin.path`. 
E.g. if you have two plugins and `plugin.path=/opt/connectors`, 
path of the first plugin is `/opt/connectors/confluentinc-kafka-connect-http-1.0.3/`, 
the second path is `/opt/connectors/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-5.3.1/`

Comment: @ Iskuskov Alexander - you are right, when I changed path it tries to load plugins from each directory inside confluent- 5.3.2/... however in both cases I see its able to find and load plugins from debezium, I added detailed logs in my original question.. still same issue .

Comment: @user837593, please show output of `curl localhost:8083/connector-plugins` command.

Comment: @ Iskuskov Alexander -Kafka connect stops after connector error, so port 8083 not available                            [2020-01-10 08:40:43,810] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:66)
[2020-01-10 08:40:43,810] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:244)

Comment: But if I run same in distributed mode, and run curl command, out put is pasted in question because of char limit here

Comment: I think your problem is in your config: you have to set `mongodb.user` property (see [example](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/debezium-connect-mongodb/index.html#start-the-debezium-mongodb-connector)).

Comment: @user837593, tell me please did you check your config?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your inputs. There was no issue with the config. Issue was that by default connector has source='admin' configured and the DB server I was trying to connect didn't had any admin as authentication. Seems like this is known issue. I used another test DB with no Authentication Database and that helped

Comment: @user837593, great! I hope I was helpful to you! If my answer is correct, please vote up and accept it